# Word for a dish that looks unpleasant

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a noun to describe a dish that looks unpleasant & unappetizing. The situation may be that someone makes their best to cook and serve you this dish and this cooking puts this person out too much.

However, it turns out that the result is disgusting and makes you feel sick.

[image: Dish presented to look like a creature]

Comment: What's wrong with unappetizing? What did a thesaurus suggest?

Comment: To a well-meaning friend as in your example, I use **interesting** or **different** in such situations, sometimes preceded with "certainly."

Comment: Seeing as the animal is a creepy crawly how about: "that dish gives me the creeps", "it's creepy",  or (once at home) you could say it looks like vomit regurgitated. :)

Comment: 2 words possibilities: "inedible food", "Sickening meal" or "nauseating dish".

Comment: @Mitch I want a noun.

Comment: Please [edit] this to say that you want a noun, and also to show us how you would like to use it in a sentence.

Comment: Sorry, but I think the pickle-scaled baby dragon is totes adorbs.

Comment: And it looks yummy.

Comment: +1 @ErnestFriedman-Hill : totally adorable yes, but I see him more as a baby sea serpent and without those pickle-scales he’d surely be **an abomination** in the eyes of some!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The noun **[slop](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slop)** is defined by Oxford Dictionaries as being:

> 1.2. Unappetizing semi-liquid food.
>
> - I may have called that food slop, but compared to this I consider it a meal fit for kings!

Cambridge Dictionaries says

> ​food that is more ​liquid than it should be and is ​therefore ​unpleasant:
>
> - *Have you ​tried the [slop](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slop) that they ​call ​stew in the ​canteen?*

Alternatively, **swill**

> ​food that is very ​bad:
>
> - *I ​refuse to ​eat the [swill](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swill?topic=animal-food) that they ​serve in the ​canteen.*

Comment: Oh! That's good. "Swill" goes well in this context.

Comment: Swill is too mild a term for the atrocity in that picture. I'll stick with nasty :-)

Comment: @Michael_B but *nasty* is an adjective, and it can be attributed to practically anything :) It does look pretty revolting though.

Answer (score 2):

I would call it **"strange"** or **"off-putting"** as suggested by Brian Donnovan.

> - disgusting (adj) "so unpleasant to see, smell, taste, consider, etc., that you feel slightly sick" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disgusting)
> - off-putting (adj)  not pleasing or likable : causing you to feel dislike of someone or something. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off-putting)

Some cooks have very good ideas on how to make a dish look most appetizing. Others, however skilled, do exactly the opposite. More often than not, their goal is to shock those who see their "masterpiece". The pictures below illustrate that.

figure 1. brilliant and mouthwatering sweets
figure 2. **deleted on request**. Considered offensive and shocking by some.

[image]

To a Western World culture, **the food in your picture certainly looks "strange"** to say the least. But I wouldn't be surprised if it were appreciated in some regions.  Then again, my second picture will certainly be considered disgusting, unseemly and offensive by most people.

Comment: *Disgusting* is a strong word. For milder cases, try *off-putting.*

Comment: I described a well-meaning person that was not good at cooking and made a nasty thing instead of a delicious dish.  Your second picture is obviously offensive and does not work in my context. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Everything single part of that dish looks *nasty*.

#### Nasty

> highly unpleasant, especially to the senses; physically nauseating. ~
>   *[Google definition](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=nasty%20definition%20dictionary)*